# Laravel - Add two column into existing table using php artisan make:migration at once

Tags: laravel, migration

I am new to `laravel` and I want to know that can't we add two column into existing table using

```
php artisan make:migration
```

at once for Ex. if my users table contain `id`,`user_name` and now I want to add two new column like as `user_phone` and `user_email` in one

```
php artisan make:migration add_user_phone_to_users_table add_user_email_to_users_table
```

something like that ? I am very sorry If my question is wrong.. I can add new field one by one into two separate migration but want to know is it possible to add two new column to existing table at once. Thanks in advance and I hope I will get a satisfied answer.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question: split it into text and samples and perhaps provide sample that works for you and base for sample that you are going to create

Comment: @rudolf_franek I got the answer .thank you I will keep in mind that next time whenever I will ask question I will come up with nice formatted text..Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

You are right by creating a new migration, `php artisan make:migration add_email_and_phone_number_to_users --table=users`

In the migration you can add the code for this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone_number')->nullable();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['email', 'phone_number']);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am so happy.. This is what exactly I want Thank you so much..As well as thank you so much for all..
This is my first question so I am uable to upvote your answer..

Answer (score 0):

when adding more columns to an existing table using another migration, you need to define the `table`

```
php artisan make:migration name_of_the_migration --table="table_name"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but my question is can we add two new column to exising table in one statement 
php artisan make:migration add_user_phone_to_users_table  add_uers_email_to_users_table --table="users"
Is it possible?

Comment: what you need to understand here is, the name of the migration doesn't matter. execute this command and it will create a new migration file and you can add as  many columns inside that migration file.

Comment: Thanks Thakara Thijs Bouwes answer help me out but thank you too for your great effort..Keep it up..